# How to add a message property in node azure iot sdk

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-node-sdk

With the azure C sdk it's possible to add properties to the message envelope using `Map_AddOrUpdate(propMap, "propKey", propText)`.  Is there something similar?  I'm using

```
const Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
const Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
const Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

client = Client.fromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, Protocol);
// misc code
 return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    client.sendEvent(message,(err,res) => {
      if ( err ) {
        logger.error(TAG,'Failed to send message: ', err.toString())
        reject(err)
      }
      if (res) logger.info(TAG,'Send status: ' + res.constructor.name);
      resolve(res)
    })
  })
```

I was unable to find anything in the client interface that allowed me to set envelope properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do: `message.properties.add('yourProp', 'val')`. You might find [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device.js) useful.